# Apache Tomcat HTTP Status 404 error after Java web app deployment

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, deployment, web-deployment

For the past 2 months, I've been working on a project for my final year in uni. I've developed a web app in Java (Eclipse) and I used to test it by benefiting the Tomcat servlet containers. However, at the final stage now I want to deploy it on the university servers, but I am experiencing a strange error. I am not sure what I've haven't configured correctly on the uni server-side, that's why I will be thankful if anyone can direct me to resolutions to the problem.

The problem is that in Eclipse when I launch the app I am given a login form, which when I type my credentials let me in my account. However, on the university server-side after I generated a war that I placed in the webapps folder I restarted the Tomcat server, but I am getting HTTP Status 404 - /auction/login error after I submit my credentials.

The conclusion is that in Eclipse everything runs smoothly, however, on the university server-side I get HTTP Status 404 - /auction/login after I type my credentials in the login form

I've checked many solutions discussed in here, but nothing seemed to be similar to what I'm experiencing. I have suspicions I've missed to configure something on the university side, but I am not sure what.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add the login form here. May be the address is absolute.

Comment: @mohammad_1m2 what do you mean to add the login form here? Should I provide the code or ?

Comment: @mohammad_1m2 please find the post updated

Comment: pls add the login.jsp file in your question. Also add the servlet mapping and your servlet code. Did you use any framework in your project?